# Text Files, and New Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have this code to write a txt file I am just wondering why every time I type \n in the input it doesn't create a newline so like this.

```
This is the example txt file\n it doesn't create a new line\n how can I make it do it?
```

This is the code

```
def create():
     path = input("What file would you like to create: ")
     output_file = open(path, 'x')
     text = input("What would you like to write? ")
     output_file.write(text)
     output_file.close()
def append():
     path = input("What file would you like to append: ")
     output_file = open(path, 'a')
     text = input("What would you like to write?")
     output_file.writelines(["\n", text])
     output_file.close()
write = input("Would you like to write something today, or edit? ")
if write == "Write":
        create()
if write == "Edit":
        append()
```

Comment: The answer is more or less given in your question: to write the txt '"\n" you type two characters '\' and 'n' (thus taken together called an escape sequence). A newline, or to be more precise, a linefeed (LF, 'advance down one line'), on other other hand is just one 'character', i.e. one byte (value decimal 10, or hex 0xA); it is usually represented in texts, such as your question, by the two typeable characters '\' and 'n'. (It depends on the interpreter (like python) or compiler (e.g. for a C-source file) on how to 'translate' that escape-sequence.)

Comment: @Roadowl So if I typed \n\ would that work? because I was reading in some posts about that...

Comment: Work to do what?

Comment: Here's an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410812/how-do-you-input-escape-sequences-in-python

Comment: Not an answer, but can I suggest using \r\n just to keep things neat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace:

```
def create():
    path = input("What file would you like to create: ")
    output_file = open(path, 'x')
    text = input("What would you like to write? ")
    output_file.write(text.replace('\\n', '\n'))
    output_file.close()
def append():
    path = input("What file would you like to append: ")
    output_file = open(path, 'a')
    text = input("What would you like to write?")
    output_file.writelines(text.replace('\\n', '\n'))
    output_file.close()
write = input("Would you like to write something today, or edit? ")
if write == "Write":
    create()
if write == "Edit":
    append()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simplified answer.

```py
input = input("Would you like to Write a new document, or Edit an existing one?  ")
if input == Write:
    file = open(path, "w")
    file.write(text)
    file.write("\r\n")
    file.close()
if input == Edit:
    file = open(path, "a")
    file.write(text)
    file.write("\r\n")
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `\n` doesn't work with `input` is mentioned in [How do you input escape sequences in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410812/how-do-you-input-escape-sequences-in-python). The `input` function doesn't recognize any escape sequences, such as `\n`,  because it interprets the text literally.

To interpret `\n` as a new line from `text`, have these imports and adjust the arguments for `write()` and `writelines()` allowing a user to input, `This is the example txt file\n it doesn't create a new line\n how can I make it do it?` to include new lines:

```py
import ast # Add imports
import shlex

def create():
    path = input("What file would you like to create: ")
    output_file = open(path, 'x')
    text = input("What would you like to write? ")
    output_file.write(ast.literal_eval(shlex.quote(text))) # Evaluate escape sequences
    output_file.close()


def append():
    path = input("What file would you like to append: ")
    output_file = open(path, 'a')
    text = input("What would you like to write?")
    output_file.writelines(["\n", ast.literal_eval(shlex.quote(text))]) # Evaluate escape sequences
    output_file.close()

write = input("Would you like to write something today, or edit? ")
if write == "Write":
    create()
if write == "Edit":
    append()
```