# take newline character as input

Tags: python, input, newline

I've a small script to find and replace strings since most text editors fail to do so for multiple files.
When I pass newline character(\n) as input, the python converts the slash to double slash and it no more stays are newline character. So, my search and replace fails.
[image]

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Adding suggested solutions here:

**Solution 1.**

As suggested by @Xu Qiushi

```
from shlex import quote as q

from ast import literal_eval as le

a = le(q(input()))
```

allows to take \n as it is.

**Solution 2:**

Directly providing a dictionary as dict_a = {'।\s' : '।\n'}

etc. works fine for search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get multiline input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user)

Comment: Actually, I'm not taking multiline strings. I'm just trying to take inputs for regex search.

Comment: One way may be to input \n and let it be converted to \\n by python and then replace every \\ with \.
Does that look good.?

Comment: Is it possible that I'm being fooled by output like this post says:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/301075/10866036

Comment: Does this answered your question? "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410812/how-do-you-input-escape-sequences-in-python"

Comment: @Xu Qiushi Yes, This worked for point of input. Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround solution :

```
a= input()
if (a == "\\n"):
  a="\n"
b = """hello
lad"""
print(a in b)
```

I wouldn't recommend user entering special character

Solution 2:

```
`a=input()
 if(a == "new"):
   a="\n"`
```

Comment: Yes, it appears that there is no way apart from replacing \\n with \n.

Comment: Now, just consider that if I've to do it for \s \t and whatever not, it'll be more troublesome.
Trying to use string_a.replace('\\', '\') doesn't work and using string_a.replace('\\', '"\\"') gives undesired result.
Any suggestions here.

Comment: Python converts it since it's a bad idea letting users enter special character may break the program

Comment: So, it appears that instead of using \n, I've to enter literal as suggested by @Xu Qiushi.
But, I wonder whether the regex search will work then?

Comment: You could use a =ast.literal_eval(shlex.quote(a))

Comment: yes, this is enough for now.
BTW, if there were no solutions for this, then providing {search_string : replacement_string} library was the only way.